# PHP - When browsers save csv file, the content of the csv appends the html page at beginning of csv file

Tags: php, csv

My php code saves the .csv file on the server. When I get the .csv file directly from server, its content is good and I can view it in Excel. But in my webpage, when I click to save the file, the content saved on my computer is bringing the content of the html file, followed by the content of csv file. What could be wrong ?

Here is the piece of code where I have issue:

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($my_query, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS))
{       
    //store content in csv format into $mymessage
}

$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
fwrite($handle, $mymessage);
fclose($handle);

header("Content-type: application/x-file-to-save");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$my_file");
readfile("$my_file");
exit;
```

============================================================

Here's how the content looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Cp1252">
<title>ABCDEF...</title>
</head>
<body>
<font size="4" color=blue><a><b><i><u>12345678</u></i></b></a></font>
<br></br>
...

CSV REPORT EXTRACTED AS OF, 2014/03/25 08:18:16

SERVER,APP-SERVER
server1,weblogic
server2,jboss
server3,weblogic
server4,weblogic
server5,websphere
...
```

Appreciate in advance.

Comment: Is there a way to clear out buffers before prompting user to save file ?

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be like some kind of routing problem. Your php page charging the CSV data should be the only one called. But it seems like you are using a framework or you may have an include somewhere or you have a rewrite on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got it resolved. I had to add ob_end_clean() before $handle() and before first header(). With that done, any buffered output was cleared out and csv file was saved with no "extra" content.

Thank you all that spent time trying to help me.